# Handling Single Record in razor view using ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using ASP.Net MVC3 with C#.

Currently I am trying to pass a single database record to my view page creating my own ad rotator.

Here is my controller code.

```
var rand = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);
int numIterations = 0;
numIterations = rand.Next(1, 2);

CJAd cjad = db.CJAds.Single(c => c.category_id == 1 && c.ad_active == true && c.id == numIterations);

ViewData["SideBarAd"] = cjad;
```

Every code sample I have seen shows how to cycle through multiple records. How do I turn the ViewData on the view page into a database object and display it?

It tried this

```
@ViewData["SideBarAd"].ad_url
```

But received the error

CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ad_url' and no extension method 'ad_url' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you trying to display one object in the ViewData on your view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just include the CJAd in your view model?  That's much simpler.

However, if you're determined, use ViewBag instead, then you don't need to cast.

```
ViewBag.SideBarAd = cjad;
```

in your view (assuming SideBarAd is a string that is the url to your ad)

```
<img src="@ViewBag.SideBarAd"/>
```

Comment: I will be including multiple database lookups in one page so I don't make the page exclusive to the ad model.

Comment: @GregGoodwin - you don't have to.  That's why ViewModels exist.  You can wrap multiple sub-models into a single ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<div>@ViewBag.SideBarAd.SomeProperty</div>
```

where `SomeProperty` is a property of the `CJAd` class that you want to display in the view.

This being said, I would recommend you using view models instead of ViewData:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var rand = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    int numIterations = 0;
    numIterations = rand.Next(1, 2);
    var cjad = db.CJAds.Single(c => c.category_id == 1 && c.ad_active == true && c.id == numIterations);

    return View(cjad);
}
```

and then in the corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model AppName.Models.CJAd
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeProperty)</div>
```

Also for displaying Ads on all pages you could take a look at the [Html.Action helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). It could greatly simplify your code and dissociate it with the main logic of the controller.

Comment: I will be including multiple database lookups in one page so I don't make the page exclusive to the ad model.

Comment: @GregGoodwin, of course that you can. You should define a view model. A view model is a class that will contain all the information that the view needs. So it will have properties containing the Ad and it will have properties about the other stuff you need. Then in the controller action you will aggregate all this information and pass a single view model to the view. And in the view you will get Intellisense and strong typing.